# How to get epoch time after keeping the same time but changing timezone in Python 3.9+?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I have an epoch timestamp - 1657315800.

This translates to `July 8 2022 2:30PM` in my local timezone (Pacific).

What I want to do is keep the same time reading but change the timezone to GMT (`July 8 2022 2:30PM GMT`) and then take the epoch timestamp, which should be 1657290000

How do I do that?

Script -

```
current_datetime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1657315800)
print(current_datetime.hour) # Prints 14 (the same hour as in current timezone of Los Angeles)
# Do some operation to get new_epoch_time
print(new_epoch_time) # Prints 1657290000
```

One observation is that the `current_datetime.hour` prints the same hour as observed by Daylight Savings. I need to change it irrespective of that.

Comment: That isn't how epoch works. Epoch is UTC (GMT).

Comment: @PeterWood I know. But there's a problem I need to solve and adjusting timezone on same object didnt do it